# Javascript testing framework that provides "deep stubbing"

Tags: javascript, testing

Is there a javascript testing framework that provides deep stubbing?

mockito in python are deep by default.

```
>> import mock
>> m = mock.Mock()
>> m.foo()
<Mock name='mock.foo()' id='4412582928'>
>> m.foo.bar()
<Mock name='mock.foo().bar()' id='4412583312'>
```

jsmockito does not do this by default. Is there any javascript testing framework that provides this? 
I have tried.. `jsmockito`, and `sinon` however none of them provided me with this feature.